# Oracle Database 11g Express: Data Pump Export

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to invoke the expdp (Data Pump Export) command, but I got an error:

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin\XE\dpdump>expdp test/test@DEVICES CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY FILE=FLEET.DMP

Export: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Vie Sep 22 12:46:30 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

UDE-12154: operation generated ORACLE error 12154
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

and here the file tsnames.ora :

```
 DEVICES =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 212.137.78.211)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = DEVICES)
    )
  )
```

and

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\admin\XE\dpdump>tnsping DEVICES

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 22-SEP-2017 16:00:17

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

Comment: Can you do a `tnsping DEVICES`? What's the output of `lsnrctl status` on the server? I'm guessing probably your SID is wrong, but it could be other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e41945/admintools.htm#NETAG272 please see this post, thear write corectly, but I thinking you write wrong database name

Answer (score 0):

First try what @kfinity suggested, it is good advice. If that doesn't add clarity, try:

> sqlplus test/test@device

That will probably not connect in your case. I am on Windows, you will need to do similar if you are on UNIX:

```
set ORACLE_SID=DEVICE
sqlplus test/test
```

If this connects, retry your IMPD command. If it doesn't, check out the SQLNET configuration file at %oracle_home%\network\admin\sqlnet.ora.

If it has an entry similar to

> NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = WORLD

you need to add *.WORLD* to your command, as in

> expdp test/test@DEVICES.WORLD CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY FILE=FLEET.DMP